# how to go to choice text box Microsoft access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba

have a problem,how to go to choice text box if previous text box value show more 0 value?

have 4 text box and 1 "next button"

Text box 1 - Qty reject in numbering. If the value show "0",process will continue to "next Button",
but If value show more then "0" [1,2,3 and more] it will be go to text box 2 after that go to "next button".that mean it not direct go to "next button" if value more then "0".
how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Private Sub Text0_AfterUpdate()
    If Text0.Value = 0 Then
        btnNext.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Also set the tab order of your controls in the desired order for the case that Text0 is greater than 0.

Set tab order:
[image]